# In array operator in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

Is there a way to test whether an array contains a specified element?

e.g., something like:

```
array=(one two three)

if [ "one" in ${array} ]; then
...
fi
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A for loop will do the trick.

```
array=(one two three)

for i in "${array[@]}"; do
  if [[ "$i" = "one" ]]; then
    ...
    break
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
array=(one two three)
if [[ "${array[*]}" =~ "one" ]]; then
  echo "'one' is found"
fi
```

Comment: That works unless the array is '`array=(scone honest)`' which really can't be said to contain an element 'one' but would be matched by the `=~` operator.

Comment: @Jonathan oops, you're right. I vote for [@Frank 's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852446/in-array-operator-in-bash/5852473#5852473) then.

Comment: Not really solving this issue *in general*, but might be helpful in many cases (at least when each array element consists of a single word only): make the regexp (right-site) `=~ "\bone\b"` to match whole words only. I like the simplicity!

Answer (score 7):

I got an function 'contains' in my .bashrc-file:

```
contains () 
{ 
    param=$1;
    shift;
    for elem in "$@";
    do
        [[ "$param" = "$elem" ]] && return 0;
    done;
    return 1
}
```

It works well with an array:

```
contains on $array && echo hit || echo miss
  miss
contains one $array && echo hit || echo miss
  hit
contains onex $array && echo hit || echo miss
  miss
```

But doesn't need an array:

```
contains one four two one zero && echo hit || echo miss
  hit
```

Answer (score 2):

I like using grep for this:

```sh
if echo ${array[@]} | grep -qw one; then
  # "one" is in the array
  ...
fi
```

(Note that both `-q` and `-w` are non-standard options to grep: `-w` tells it to work on whole words only, and `-q` ("quiet") suppresses all output.)

Comment: Note this also only works if elements are single words (as placed in the example). Using it to check for the element "one" in `array=("one man" "two horses")` would wrongly yield it did (as "one" is a word *contained*, i.e. part of, the first element), though it's not (as a stand-alone element).

Answer (score 0):

```
array="one two three"
if [ $(echo "$array" | grep one | wc -l) -gt 0 ] ; 
  then echo yes; 
fi
```

If that's ugly, you could hide it away in a function.

Comment: If you egrep for word boundaries, `egrep "\bone\b"`, you will prevent array="onex two three" to match on 'one'. ``echo "$array" | egrep "\bone\b"  && echo hit || echo miss`` is sufficient - wc-l and -gt0 is superflous.

Comment: No need for the test ('[').  Just use the return value of grep.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to check whether an element is in array, another approach

```
case "${array[@]/one/}" in 
 "${array[@]}" ) echo "not in there";;
 *) echo "found ";;
esac
```

Comment: Doesn't this have the same issue as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5853138/2533433) – i.e. echo "found" also on "honest"? `foo=(honest oneman); echo "${foo[@]/one/}"` gives `hst man`, and thus would return "found" with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
In_array() {
    local NEEDLE="$1"
    local ELEMENT

    shift

    for ELEMENT; do
        if [ "$ELEMENT" == "$NEEDLE" ]; then
            return 0
        fi
    done

    return 1
}

declare -a ARRAY=( "elem1" "elem2" "elem3" )
if In_array "elem1" "${ARRAY[@]}"; then
...
```

A nice and elegant version of the above.

Answer (score 0):

```
in_array() {
    local needle=$1 el
    shift
    for el in "$@"; do
        if [ "$el" = "$needle" ]; then
            return 0
        fi
    done
    return 1
}

if in_array 1 1 2 3; then
    echo true
else
    echo false
fi

# alternatively
a=(1 2 3)
if in_array 1 "${a[@]}"; then
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/bash

envs=("production" "prod" "stage" "test" "dev");
APP_ENV="prod"

if [[ ${envs[*]} =~ $APP_ENV ]]
then
  echo "value found"
else
  echo "value not found"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

```
OPTIONS=('-q','-Q','-s','-S')

find="$(grep "\-q" <<< "${OPTIONS[@]}")"
if [ "$find" = "${OPTIONS[@]}" ];
then
    echo "arr contains -q"
fi
```